# How do I list all the attributes of an object in Python?

Tags: python, object, attributes, praw

I'm trying to write a Reddit bot using Praw, and this is my function:

`submission = reddit.submission(mention.submission.id)`

(I have previously defined `reddit = praw.Reddit()` and whatnot, so submission should give me a [submission object](http://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code_overview/models/submission.html).

Firstly, I want to check if the submission is a self post, or a link. I can do that by checking `submission.is_self`. However, out of curiosity, I tried printing `dir(submission)` and `submission.__dict__`, and neither lists `is_self` as an attribute of the object.

Why is that so? And how can I reliably find all the attributes of the object, without digging into the source code of the library itself? Praw's documentation is a bit lacking in this regard.

Answer (score 3):

The built in `dir()` method is used to list all attributes:

```
>>> class MyClass():
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.foo = 1
... 
>>> c = MyClass()
>>> dir(c)
['__doc__', '__init__', '__module__', 'foo']
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

PRAW uses `__getattr__` magic to dynamically get and set object attributes (see RedditBase class in `praw/models/reddit/base.py`). That's why `dir()` does not show it.

`is_self` does not exist anywhere in the source code, as this string is based on data received from reddit.